# Visual Studio Intellisense for CSS via CDN

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

When referencing CSS via CDN, Visual Studio shows "Unknown CSS class" error.
My CSS reference is:

```
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My HTML tag that throws error:

```
    <div class="row">
```

I know there is a way to work around using false condition:

```
<% if (false) { %>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

But that is kind of hacking and too much hassle. Does anybody know how Microsoft officially address this CSS intellisense via CDN issue?